# How can I scroll up in tty?

Tags: linux, tty, scrolling

When I work in a tty (ALT 1-6), is annoy not see previous comands output. In tty is posible scroll up, with a keyboard shorcut?

Comment: Please provide more information. If this is in a window, what program are you using for a terminal window?

Comment: Shift page-up I believe